# Laravel 4 workbench class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to develop a package in laravel 4 - my first attempt at a package. 
I found a couple of tutorials which I've tried to follow:

```
http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench
```

and

```
http://culttt.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-laravel-4-package/
```

and of course in the official documentation.

I've followed the basic structure to create the framework. However on loading the app I get a class not found error. This relates directly to the serviceprovider I have placed in the app.php file.

here's my entry in the providers array:

```
'Longestdrive\Calendar\CalendarServiceProvider'
```

My folder structure is:

```
 laravel/workbench/longestdrive/calendar/src/Longestdrive/Calendar
```

My service provider has the following entries:

```
<?php namespace Longestdrive\Calendar;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CalendarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('longestdrive/calendar');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return array();
    }

}
```

I've double checked to spelling and ran a composer dump-autoload both from the root of the project and the root of the package.

I've run out of ideas for solving the class not found  any ideas where I've gone wrong?

The line producing the error is this one:

```
C:\wamp\www\googleapi\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Update:
I ran a composer update as suggested in the workbench/package folder with a response nothing to update. I then ran composer at the root of the project and an error was produced:

```
[RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Longestdrive\Calendar\CalendarServiceProvider' not found
   in C:\wamp\www\googleapi\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRe
  pository.php on line 123
```

I probably posted the wrong error line earlier. The full exception response is:

```
Class 'Longestdrive\Calendar\CalendarServiceProvider' not found
```

THe error extract:

```
* @param \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app
* @param string $provider
* @return \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
*/
public function createProvider(Application $app, $provider)
{
return new $provider($app);
}
```

which I assume relates to the service provider loader not finding the CalendarServiceProvider?

Comment: The problem isn't really on your class, since what it can't find is `Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRespository`. Did you remember to `composer update`?

Comment: Hi - updated post above. I tested by removing my service provider entry from the service provider array and the error disappears.

Comment: It feels to me that the app is not searching in the workbench folder for my service provider? How can I check this?

Answer (score 45):

I found that running composer install from within the workbench/[vendor]/[package] folder solved the problem.

Comment: This needs to be in the Laravel documentation, seems to be an essential step that's omitted from the official [Package Development](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages) introduction.

Answer (score 21):

I encountered the same error, so I went deeper on its flow to knew what happens.

So dissecting a little bit basically, in the bootstrap phase, when `bootstrap/autoload.php` is loaded it runs at the end:

```
if (is_dir($workbench = __DIR__.'/../workbench'))
{
    Illuminate\Workbench\Starter::start($workbench);
}
```

This requires **EVERY** `workbench/vendor/package/**/**/**/autoload.php` he found (by using Symfony Finder Component)

```
$finder->in($path)->files()->name('autoload.php')->depth('<= 3');
```

### **That's important** because it's expecting to find `workbench/vendor/package/vendor/autoload.php`.

Successively in `bootstrap/start.php` it gets the 'providers' defined in `config/app.php` and try to load each of them:

```
$providers = $config['providers'];
$app->getProviderRepository()->load($app, $providers);
```

and then in `ProviderRepository.php`

```
foreach ($providers as $provider)
{
    $instance = $this->createProvider($app, $provider);
```

so we'll end up with:

```
public function createProvider(Application $app, $provider)
{
    return new $provider($app);
```

where it tried to create an instance of a class isn't really autoloaded. **And so that's why the exception thrown!**

### In conclusion...

- As @Ray said, by removing his Service from `'providers' => array(` no error is thrown cause `return new $myServiceDeclaredInProviderArray($app);` never fires for that service.
- As @Andrew Holt said

> I found that running composer install from within the workbench/[vendor]/[package] folder solved the problem.

He's absolutely right because this create the autoload vendor dir and files, and everything works as we expect it to because it finds the autoload files:

```
$finder->in($path)->files()->name('autoload.php')->depth('<= 3');
```

- Me

  > `php artisan dump-autoload` works as well if you remove the service from the providers array

Comment: Thanks. You answer helped me the most with the same problem. So the short answer is: run the dump-autoload BEFORE adding the service to the providers array. This should be made clearer [in the guide](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#creating-a-package)!

Comment: Creating a new workbench package generates a composer.json file. Running "php artisan dump-autoload" was not producing any error output, but I was missing author information and autoloading was not working. Once I entered author name and email, the dump-autoload command got autoload working without having to run composer manually from the vendor package.

Comment: Andrew's fix worked for me - thanks for digging deeper into the underlying reasons for this, was great to know as someone just starting with Laravel & wanting to know how it all works internally (:

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **@ilpaijin**'s and **@Andrew Holt**'s answer, there sometimes comes the need (when there's a new version of Laravel) to run `composer update` within the `workbench/vendor/package` folder.

Also, as noted [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=16607), the `composer.json` within the package must require the same version of `illuminate/support` as the one required of `laravel/framework` in the project root's `composer.json`.

Thanks to **@biscii** note that one should use:

```
"illuminate/support": "4.1.x"
```

instead of

```
"illuminate/support": "4.x"
```