# Laravel Package Development simple function does not work

Tags: php, laravel, package

Sorry for the bad title, but I had no idea to give a good title for my problem.

I created a package with the workbench. And now I have a package. Let's say strernd/mypkg
Inside the workbench directory `Strernd/Mypkg` I've got following code:
http://laravel.io/bin/oNzoa

Why does `Mypkg::test()`work and `$mypkg = new Mypkg(); $mypkg->test();` not? (Inside my app)
The error is 
`Call to undefined method Strernd\Mypkg\Facades\Mypkg::test()Call to undefined method Strernd\Mypkg\Facades\Mypkg::test()`

I think I'm not understanding some basic principles of PHP here. I'm more like a copy&paste / try&error "developer", but it works out well in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

When using it the 'static' way, Laravel is accessing the facade you wrote and instantiating the underlying class, then calling the method on that instance.  When you are calling the `test` method with `new Mypkg`, you are actually instantiating the *facade* class, and not the underlying class.  That facade class does not have a `test` method on it, hence the error.

Try it like this:

```
use Strernd\Mypkg as MypkgActual;

$mypkg = new MypkgActual;
$mypkg->test();
```

I believe that, because your facade and actual class implementation have the same exact class name, you're running in to a pseudo-class name conflict with Laravel's facade system winning out.  You can also try changing the name of your facade to `MypkgFacade`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me: `Class 'Strernd\Mypkg' not found`
Is there a pretty way to do this?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18499393/697370).  You may need to run `composer install` from within your `workbench/[vendor]/[package]` directory.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Would it be a solution to make another class in my package like `Car` and then use something like `$car = Mypkg::makecar()`. I would get an Car instance then, wouldn't I?