# Deploying Laravel workbench package with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Laravel web application that includes a package I'm developing in workbench. The package is part of the app's git repo. The app is hosted in an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

When I deploy the app using `eb deploy` I get the following error in eb-activity.log (from `eb logs`):

```
...
(output of composer package fetches)
...
Generating autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Me\MyPackage\MyPackageServiceProvider' not found in /var/app/ondeck/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Me\\MyPackage\\MyPackageServiceProvider' not found","file":"\/var\/app\/ondeck\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Me\MyPackage\MyPackageServiceProvider' not found in /var/app/ondeck/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
```

I saw a similar error on my dev machine that I solved by running `composer install` in the workbench package directory as described in [Laravel 4 workbench class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499393/laravel-4-workbench-class-not-found). The problem is that I can't run composer on my package before EB runs composer on the app Vendor directory. The `commands` block of the config file is too early - the files aren't on the server yet - and the container_commands block is too late because it happens after EB runs composer.

How can I run my package composer first?

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved this, although it feels a bit hacky. EB won't run composer automatically if there is a vendor directory in the root of the app, so...

1. Edit `/.gitignore` and remove the line that says /vendor
2. Create `/vendor/.gitignore` with the following content and add it to git. This adds the `vendor` directory with the single `.gitignore` file to git but ignores the rest of the vendor package subdirectories (which will be filled in by composer during deployment).

   ```
   # ignore everything except .gitignore
   !.gitignore
   *
   ```
3. You probably already have a composer deployment config file in `/.ebextensions` but just in case here's the whole contents of mine (called `01composersettings.config`) since the other commands took some investigation as well. The two commands specific to my problem are `01installWorkbenchPackages` that runs before `02installPackages`.

   ```
   commands:
       01updateComposer:
           command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

   option_settings:
     - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
       option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
       value: /root

   container_commands:
       01installWorkbenchPackages:
           command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar install -d /var/app/ondeck/workbench/me/my-package"
       02installPackages:
           command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar install"
       03optimize:
           command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize"
       04storagePermissions:
           command: "chmod -fR 755 /var/app/ondeck/app/storage"
   ```
4. Make sure `/.ebextensions/01composersettings.config` is also part of the git index (`git ls-tree -r master --name-only` is handy to check that all the files are there, including the `vendor` directory with just `.gitignore` in it)
5. Run `eb deploy`